# expo-auth-session, how to get redirected to the app, when not using a local redirectUri

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, expo, react-native

I'm trying to make an authentication functionality in my app, so when I press the login button, a web browser opens and I get to verify my account, and then I get a token in the URL, the problem is that in order for me to get redirected to my app, I need to make the redirect_uri as so `AuthSession.makeRedirectUri( 'gecond://' )`

but the website from where I'm getting my authentication doesn't allow this type of redirect_uri ( this is the URI that's being used: "https://preprod.autenticacao.gov.pt/oauth/askauthorization?redirect_uri=exp%3A%2F%2F192.168.2.26%3A19000&client_id=123456789&response_type=token&state=UOgf2pE6S0"),
it only allows a specific redirect_uri (like so "https://preprod.autenticacao.gov.pt/oauth/askauthorization?redirect_uri='https://preprod.autenticacao.gov.pt/OAuth/Authorized'&client_id=123456789&response_type=token&state=UOgf2pE6S0"), but when I use this URI, I do manage to get an access token in the URL of the page, but I'm not redirected back to my app.
I'm fairly new to this type of topic, so I might be missing a few steps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure you misread the documentation. The reply URL is where you add you application's page where the user is redirected after login.
The URL you used is the example URL from the documentation.

Please check the [official documentation](https://www.autenticacao.gov.pt/documents/20126/0/Autentica%C3%A7%C3%A3o.Gov+-+Manual+de+Integra%C3%A7%C3%A3o+v1.5.4.pdf/82d87ff8-e046-d69f-cca5-38d319f7afa5?t=1610443249238).